# nvd3 adding point to linechart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

I am trying to create realtime linechart based on notifcations that i am getting. I have looked in examples - http://jsfiddle.net/kaliatech/4TMMD/
however i cannot make it work, the rate is being updated and data is inserted into the array, but i am getting in the plot only one point which is always the first one

```
this.data = [{            
    key: "New Incidents Rate",
    values: getData()
}];


function getData() {
    return that.newIncidentRate;
}

redraw();

function redraw() {

    nv.addGraph(function() {
        that.chart = nv.models.lineChart()
            .x(function(d) { return d.x })
            .y(function(d) { return d.y });
            //.color(d3.scale.category10().range());


        that.chart.xAxis
            .axisLabel('Time')
            .tickFormat(function(d) {
                return d3.time.format('%x')(new Date(d))
            });

        that.chart.yAxis
            .axisLabel('Rate')
            .tickFormat(d3.format(',r'));

        d3.select('#chart svg')
            .datum(that.data)
            //.transition().duration(500)
            .call(that.chart);

        nv.utils.windowResize(that.chart.update);

        return that.chart;
    });
}

amplify.subscribe("newIncident", function (rate) {
    $scope.newRate = rate;
    $scope.$apply();

    if (that.newIncidentRate.length > 20) {
        that.newIncidentRate.shift();
    }

    var currentTime = new Date();

    that.newIncidentRate.push({
        x: new Date(currentTime.getTime()),
        y: rate
    });

    redraw();
});
```

i have tested it more and it seems to be related to the number of points, when i take the sample all is ok (adding 30 point - fresh every time) same when adding 2 points , so i tested to keep all the points in container and always copy it to new one - falied, it seems there is a problem to increase the number of points

```
 function getData() {

    var arr = [];
    var theDate = new Date(2012, 01, 01, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    newIncidentRate.push({x:  new Date(theDate.getTime()), y: Math.random() * 100});
    theDate.setDate(theDate.getDate() + moveDate);
    ++moveDate;

    for (var d in newIncidentRate) {
        arr.push(d) ;
    }

    return arr;
}
```

full code - http://jsfiddle.net/lirazrom/Wx5bG/

Comment: If you want multiple lines, you need multiple key-value pairs.

Comment: i done want multiple lines, i want one line which grows by adding dynamically data

Comment: You don't seem to be setting `that.data` anywhere.

Comment: why do i need? --> values: getData()

Comment: You're passing `that.data` to `.datum()`, not `getData()`.

Comment: it works fine when i add it always constant bulk of points

Comment: Could you post a complete working example please?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/lirazrom/Wx5bG/

Comment: You're calling `getData` only once in that.

Comment: where? as the data , vhen accesing the values calls the getdata

Comment: In your jsfiddle, the method that generates new data is called only once.

Comment: why? in each interval i am callinf to redraw which add data to the datum which in there the getdata is called

Comment: In your jsfiddle it isn't. Log the data and check the console if you don't believe me.

Comment: what are those errors?

Comment: Error: Problem parsing d="MNaN,35" d3.v3.min.js:1
Error: Invalid value for <circle> attribute cx="NaN" 
total 0 nv.d3.js:39
Error: Problem parsing d="MZ"

Comment: I don't know -- you put the jsfiddle together.